# Chart.js canvas change label color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Got chart defined in html:

```html
<div class="chart">
        <canvas
          baseChart
          [chartType]="'line'"
          [datasets]="chartData"
          [labels]="chartLabels"
          [options]="chartOptions"
          [legend]="true"
          (chartClick)="onChartClick($event)">
        </canvas>
      </div>
```

How can I change color of label in html?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font color of legend­'s label, in the following way ...
In ts set

```
chartOptions.options.legend.labels.fontColor= 'white'; //set your desired color
```

In your case:

```
chartOptions =  { 
    responsive: true, 
    maintainAspectRatio: false, 
    fontColor: 'red',
    options:{
        legend:{
            labels:{
                fontColor:'white';//change the color
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: In my TS file got: chartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    fontColor: 'red'
  };