# How to change label color of ng2 chart in angular

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have created a bar graph using ng2 chart. The bar graph has dark background due to which labels are not visible. I want to customise label color. How can i do this??

My *component.html* code

```
       <div style="display: block;">
          <canvas baseChart [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions" [plugins]="barChartPlugins" 
            [colors]="barChartColors"
              [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType">
           </canvas>
        </div>
```

My *component.ts* code

```
    public barChartOptions:any = {
  scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
  responsive: true
 };

  public barChartLabels:string[] = ['male', 'female', 'retired'];
  public barChartType:string = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

public barChartColors:Array<any> = [
{
  backgroundColor: '#D4526E',
  borderColor: 'rgba(105,159,177,1)',
  pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(105,159,177,1)',
  pointBorderColor: '#fafafa',
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fafafa',
  pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(105,159,177)'
},
{ 
  backgroundColor: '#008FFB',
  borderColor: 'rgba(77,20,96,1)',
  pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,20,96,1)',
  pointBorderColor: '#fff',
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
  pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,20,96,1)'
},
{ 
  backgroundColor: '#E2C044',
  borderColor: 'rgba(77,20,96,1)',
  pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(77,20,96,1)',
  pointBorderColor: '#fff',
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
  pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(77,20,96,1)'
  }
 ];
public barChartData:any[] = [
  {data: [10,40,65,74,22], label: 'Govt_Jobs'},
  {data: [20,46,27,67,89], label: 'Private'},
  {data: [38,8,61,26,77], label: 'daily_wage'},
 ];
```

Comment: can u create a stackblitz project with the issue?

Comment: This has a way to change label font color and color  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596932/chart-js-canvas-change-label-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can change the font color of labels as shown below.

```
    public barChartOptions:any = {
scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
responsive: true,
legend: {
  display: true,
  labels: {
    fontColor: 'green'
  }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out how to achieve this theme change driven label color change properly. `setColorschemesOptions` of class `import { ThemeService } from 'ng2-charts';` can be used.
Here's my solution:
Let's say your chart options looks like this

```
public chartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
      labels: {
        fontColor: 'black'
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          console.log(value, ctx);
          const label = ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex];
          return label;
        },
      },
      
    }
  };
```

Now you have to subscribe to the themeChange variable in ngOnInit() and use `themeService` to set the new value of this.chartOptions.legend.labels.fontColor every time a dark theme is selected, which can be done like:

```
import { Label, SingleDataSet, ThemeService } from 'ng2-charts';

constructor(
    private themeService: ThemeService
  ) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.matService.themeSubject.subscribe((e) => {
      if(e === "purple-green" || e === "pink-bluegrey") {
        this.chartOptions.legend.labels.fontColor = "white";
        this.themeService.setColorschemesOptions(this.chartOptions);
      } else {
        this.chartOptions.legend.labels.fontColor = "black";
        this.themeService.setColorschemesOptions(this.chartOptions);
      }
    });
}
```